# Diagonalizing a matrix of operators

Tags: linear-algebra, lie-algebras, noncommutative-algebra, noncommutative-geometry

> Let $A,B,C\in\mathbb{C}[\partial_x,\partial_y]$ be differential operators. Diagonalize the matrix $$M=\begin{pmatrix}A+B&C\\-C&A-B\end{pmatrix}.$$

If $B,C$ were operators with purely complex image and $A$ an operator with real image I could've imagined that one should think on $M$ as a matrix in some version  of $SU(1,1)$. Another idea I thought about is to try and write the operators in form of continued fractions but inverting the operators explicitly can be hard. How would you proceed?

Comment: Could you say what "diagonalizing the matrix" in this context means a bit more precisely?  I'm a bit thrown off by the fact that the matrices of this form don't all commute.  For instance:
$$
\pmatrix{0&\operatorname{id}\\-\operatorname{id} & 0}, \quad 
\pmatrix{\operatorname{id} & 0\\0 & -\operatorname{id}}
$$

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I'm concerned with solving teh system $M\vec f=\vec g$ so by diagnolizing I mean writing $M=P'DP$ with $D=\begin{pmatrix}c\cdot\text{id}&0\\ 0&d\cdot \text{id}\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: Okay, so I thought you were looking for a $P$ which is independent of $A,B,C$.  My point was that this in particular is impossible because we have a non-commuting family of operators.

Comment: Also, I don't think you actually mean $c \cdot \operatorname{id}$. In particular, I wouldn't expect that $M$ should always have only the two distinct eigenvalues $c$ and $d$.

Comment: I do allow $c=d$. Is there any other way to solve the system which doesn't involve brute force?

Comment: why should we expect that this matrix of operators will have only two distinct eigenvalues?

Comment: That's a good point, I admit. So you say there's no hope for solving such systems "indirectly"?

Comment: I'm saying no such thing.  For instance, I do see a solution in the restricted case of $B = 0$, so long as you're comfortable diagonalizing differential operators (e.g. with some kind of Fourier basis).  We're just obviously going to have more than two eigenvalues; rather than $c \cdot \operatorname{id}$, we should have some diagonal operator on the diagonal.

Comment: In my system $B\neq 0$, sorry for not saying it before...